# My function isn't returning True even though the statement is True

Tags: python

Im doing my first milestone project and i can't get my function to return True if the winning conditions are met. The function should return True if the Mark ,"X" or "O", is seen 3 times in a row across the board (Tic Tac Toe). Can anyone clarify why its not returning True or False?

I first wrote my code as

```
return (board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark)
```

but it wouldn't return True. So i tried to use if and else statements for all possible winning outcomes and i still couldn't get it to return True. It only worked when i replaced return with print. The function takes in 2 arguments, Board and Mark.

Board is a list, for testing purposes I used `test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']`

Im using visual studio code and terminal to run my code.

```
def win_check(board, mark):
    return ((board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark) or # across top
            (board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark) or # across middle
            (board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # across bottom
            (board[7] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[1] == mark) or # down left
            (board[8] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[2] == mark) or # down middle
            (board[9] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # down right
            (board[7] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # diagonal
            (board[9] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[1] == mark))   # diagonal
```

I then tried using if and else statements:

```
def win_check(board, mark):
    if (board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark):
      return True # across the top
    elif(board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark):
      return True # across the middle
    elif(board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark):
      return True # across the bottom
    elif(board[7] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[1] == mark):
      return True # down the middle
    elif(board[8] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[2] == mark):
      return True # down the middle
    elif(board[9] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[3] == mark):
      return True # down the right side
    elif(board[7] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[3] == mark):
      return True # diagonal
    elif(board[9] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[1] == mark):
      return True # diagonal
    else :
      return False
```

I expect the output to be True if the winning condition is True

Comment: A *runnable* [mcve] would do this question good. Can you amend to assign a value to `board`, and otherwise get to where someone can copy-and-paste the code without changes to see the behavior themselves? (We do want the *shortest* code that can be run to see an issue, but it still needs to be code that *can be run* to see an issue).

Comment: What is `mark`?

Comment: Can you include an example of `board`?

Comment: Mark is "X" or "O"

Comment: Board would be a list that looks something like this

Comment: test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X'], when i use the function, it will check if conditions to win are met and return True, im sorry if my question is a mess. Its my first time using stack overflow so im new to this

Comment: [Edit] the details needed to reproduce into the question itself, don't just add them in comments. If `mark='X'` and you have a specific board where `X` should win, both that value and the board should be assigned as part of the question itself.

Comment: Moreover, because `return` is only valid syntax inside a function, if you're going to show us code that uses `return`, it needs to be shown *inside a function*.

Comment: Take a look at https://ideone.com/YFHZQz -- your code, unmodified, correctly detects X as winning. Please edit the question so we can tell how you were running it to *not* get that detection.

Comment: ...and see the other/second version of your code giving a correct answer at https://ideone.com/zcFS9i